# CloudCDN bucket: how to set my landing page without domain

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have a Cloud storage bucket with static files in it.

I have set up a load balancer with Cloud CDN enabled on the cloud bucket above.

When I go to the `public_IP` assigned in the load balancer I get an xml error message access denied as this is just an ip, not a landing page.

When I go to `public_ip/index.html`, then the website load.

EDIT (removing) :*The content of the bucket will only be served by a sub-domain of an external domain name, that's why I can't name my bucket as the domain name.*
It is possible to rename a bucket as a subdomain, and the landing page definition works, but the base question remains.

Is there a possibility to set the landing page for the IP address anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to configure a landing page for any Cloud Storage bucket using the gsutil command line tool. For example, the following command configures the landing page for the bucket named elving:

`gsutil web set -m index.html gs://elving`

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to configure this using the Google Cloud Console. You must use the API directly or use a tool such as gsutil. You can find more information about gsutil at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil.